# Air for Android share youtube video via my app?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, youtube, share

Having spent two days banging my head against my desk, I've decided to ask for some help...

I'm trying to share videos and other links to my air for android app that I am developing with Flash CS6. I have added to following to my manifest file:

```
    <![CDATA[
  <manifest>
        <application> 
      <activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

I know that this is supposed to trigger the activity ".ui.MyActivity" when the SEND intent is invoked. I have also added the following code to my AS code:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onAppInvoke);
function onAppInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
Status_txt.text = event.arguments.toString()
Status_txt.text += event
}
```

But i really haven't had much luck. The best result i've obtained is the opening of my app but the event.arguments array is empty. Other results include the foce closing of my app whenever other share with it or the failing of my app to compile.

Does anyone have any advice?
Thanks in advance!
Smollett

Comment: It really can't be that hard...

Comment: searched the web for the last day, and got nothing...
probably will have to do some ANE tricks...